# Macro for copying cells from one open workbook to another open workbook...if I dont knwo their file path's

Tags: excel, vba

Macro for copying cells from one open workbook to another open workbook...if I dont knwo their file path's
 PS: The code is to be written in the source workbook

Comment: If they are both open, you only need to know the workbook name. If there will only be 2 workbooks open, then you don't even need to know their name...

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this (`ThisWorkbook` is a reference to Workbook you have the VBA code):

```
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Copy
    Workbooks("Book1.xslx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Assuming both workbooks are already opened. You do not need to know the full path - only file name matters.

Comment: @Anand Read this: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/967 - it may be helpful in understanding references to workbooks.

Comment: what if i do not want to have a workbook open. and still want to push values in it